# Загрузка файлов через API Qnap

Tags: веб-программирование, api

Возникла проблема с загрузкой файлов в хранилище Qnap посредством их API.
Документация приводит в пример следующее:

```
http://IP:8080/cgi-bin/filemanager/utilRequest.cgi?func=upload&type=standard&sid=xxxx&dest_path=/Public&overwrite=1&progress=-Public-test.zip
Upload test.zip to /Public. If the file exists, overwrite the file
```

Данная конструкция мне непонятна - откуда берется файл test.zip, как его прикрепить к запросу?

Comment: `progress=-Public-test.zip` это и есть test.zip, чуть выше в api о параметре progress - `Destination file path, “/” needs to be replaced with “-”`, т.е. `-Public-test.zip` это `/Public/test.zip` что, вероятно, является путем к файлу

Comment: Это я понял. Но мне нужно загрузить файл с локального компьютера через веб-форму с использованием API. Это вообще возможно?

Comment: так запрос выше это ровно и делает. а как именно Вы собираетесь делать эти запросы? язык/фреймворк

Comment: Yii2 (PHP) с помощью ActiveForm и поля fileInput(). На сервере все сохраняется через saveAs, а вот что передать в запрос к api, чтобы он забрал файл с локальной машины - пока понять не могу

Comment: В результате выполнения запроса с путем к существующему файлу, получаю респонс от api: { "version": "5.1.0", "build": "20180501", "status": 0, "success": "true" } и файл, соответственно, не загружается